# Multilayer Perceptron - Error plateau

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to implement a multilayer perceptron with backpropagation with only one hidden layer on Matlab. The objective is to replicate a function with two I'm trying to implement a multilayer perceptron with backpropagation with only one hidden layer on Matlab. The objective is to replicate a function with two inputs and one output.

The problem I'm having is that the error starts decreasing with every epoch but it just reaches a plateau and doesn't seems to improve as seen in:

[image]

This is an image of all the errors during a single Epoch:

[image]

as you can see there are some extreme cases that are not being handled correctly

Im using:

- Weights initialized from -1 to 1
- Mean Square Error
- Variable number of hidden neurons
- Momentum
- Randomized input order
- no bias
- tanh activation  function for the hidden layer
- identity as the activation function of the output layer
- Inputs in range of -3 to 3
- Min-Max normalization of inputs

I have tried changing the number of neurons on the hidden layers, tried to lower the learning rate to really small amounts and nothing seems to help.

Here is the Matlab code:

```
clc
clear
%%%%%%%     DEFINITIONS  %%%%%%%%
i=0;
S=0;
X=rand(1000,2)*6-3; %generate inputs between -3,+3
Xval=rand(200,2)*6-3; %validation inputs
Number_Neurons=360;
Wh=rand(Number_Neurons,2)*2-1; %hidden weights
Wo=rand(Number_Neurons,1)*2-1;  %output weights
Learn=.001;% learning factor
momentumWh=0; %momentums
momentumWo=0;
a=.01;%momentum factor
WoN=Wo; %new weight

fxy=@(x,y) (3.*(1-x).^2).*(exp(-x.^2-(y+1).^2))-10.*(x./5-x.^3-y.^5).*(exp(-x.^2-y.^2))-(exp(-(x+1).^2-y.^2))./3;   %function to be replicated

fh=@(x) tanh(x); %hidden layer activation function
dfh= @(x) 1-tanh(x).^2; %derivative

fo=@(x) x; %output layer activation function
dfo= @(x) 1; %derivative

%%GRAPH FUNCTION
%[Xg,Yg]=meshgrid(X(:,1),X(:,2));
% Y=fxy(Xg,Yg);
% surf(Xg,Yg,Y)
%%%%%%%%%
Yr=fxy(X(:,1),X(:,2)); %Y real
Yval=fxy(Xval(:,1),Xval(:,2)); %validation Y
Epoch=1;
Xn=(X+3)/6;%%%min max normalization
Xnval=(Xval+3)/6;
E=ones(1,length(Yr));% error
Eval=ones(1,length(Yval));%validation error
MSE=1;

%%%%%        ITERATION    %%%%%
while 1
    N=1;
    perm=randperm(length(X(:,:))); %%%permutate inputs
    Yrand=Yr(perm);    %permutate outputs
    Xrand=Xn(perm,:);
    while N<=length(Yr) %epoch    

        %%%%%%foward pass %%%%%
        S=Wh*Xrand(N,:)'; %input multiplied by hidden weights  
        Z=fh(S); %activation function of hidden layer
        Yin=Z.*Wo; %output of hidden layer multiplied by output weights
        Yins=sum(Yin); %sum all the inputs
        Yc=fo(Yins);% activation function of output layer, Predicted Y
        E(N)=Yrand(N)-Yc; %error

        %%%%%%%% back propagation %%%%%%%%%%%%%
        do=E(N).*dfo(Yins); %delta of output layer
        DWo=Learn*(do.*Z)+a*momentumWo; %Gradient of output layer
        WoN=Wo+DWo;%New output weight
        momentumWo=DWo; %store momentum
        dh=do.*Wo.*dfh(S); %delta of hidden layer
        DWh1=Learn.*dh.*Xrand(N,1); %Gradient of hidden layer
        DWh2=Learn.*dh.*Xrand(N,2);
        DWh=[DWh1 DWh2]+a*momentumWh;%Gradient of hidden layer        
        Wh=Wh+DWh;  %new hidden layer weights
        momentumWh=DWh; %store momentum
        Wo=WoN; %update output weight
        N=N+1; %next value
    end

    MSET(Epoch)=(sum(E.^2))/length(E);  %Mean Square Error Training
    N=1;    
    %%%%%% validation %%%%%%%
    while N<=length(Yval)
        S=Wh*Xnval(N,:)';    
        Z=fh(S);
        Yin=Z.*Wo;
        Yins=sum(Yin);
        Yc=fo(Yins);
        Eval(N)=Yc-Yval(N);
        N=N+1;    
    end

    MSE(Epoch)=(sum(Eval.^2))/length(Eval);   %Mean Square Error de validacion  
    if MSE(Epoch)<=1 %stop condition
        break
    end
    disp(MSET(Epoch))
    disp(MSE(Epoch))
    Epoch=Epoch+1; %next epoch
end
```

Comment: have you tried increasing the learning rate and seeing if the error drops?

Comment: i have tried error rates from .1 to .00001 
the best rate for me was .001 with a momentum factor of .01
higher rates produce more oscilation on the MSE and actually makes the performance worse.

Comment: When i tried to learn neural network with one hidden layer, it did not learn when i provided only data with false expected results at the beginning. When expected results was "mixed" (some false, some true, some false,...) it solved the problem.

Comment: i dont understand what you are trying to say Luke

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of factors that can come into play for the particular problem that you are trying to solve:

- **The Complexity of the Problem**:  Is the problem considered easy for a neural network to solve (If using a standard dataset, have you compared the results to other studies?)
- **The Inputs**:  Are the inputs strongly related to the output?  Are there more inputs that you can add to the NN?  Are they preprocessed correctly?
- **Local Minima vs Global Minima**:  Are you sure that the problem has stopped in a local minima (A place where the NN gets stuck in learning that stops the NN from reaching a more optimal solution)?
- **Outputs**:  Are the output samples skewed in some way?  Is this a binary output kind of problem, and are there enough samples on both sides?
- **Activation Function**:  Is there another appropriate Activation Function for the problem?

Then there is the Hidden Layers, Neurons, Learning Rate, Momentum, Epochs etc. which you appear to have trialled.

Based on the chart, this is the kind of learning performance that would roughly be expected for a BPNN, however trial and error is sometimes required to optimise the result from there.

I would try to work on the above options (particularly pre-processing of data) and see if this helps in your case.

Comment: 1. i believe te problem is highly complex, see this plot: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(3*(1-X)%5E2)*(e%5E(-X%5E2-(Y%2B1)%5E2))-10*(X%2F5-X%5E3-Y%5E5)*(e%5E(-X%5E2-Y%5E2))-(e%5E(-(X%2B1)%5E2-Y%5E2))%2F3+from+-3+to+3) 
2. its a function im trying to replicate, of course the inputs are correlated
3. yes, of course the NN got stuck in a less than optimal solution
4. the function is highly erratic, i believe is making the systme noisy
5. no idea if there are other activation function that would help

data is being preprocessed with a min max normalization

Comment: Perhaps you could draw a map of the estimates from the NN to see how it lines up with the samples and see which sections are causing the most grief.  This may assist in determining what optimisations could assist in your case.

Comment: Here is a picture of the error in one epoch: [link](http://i.imgur.com/LN2o1MF.jpg) 
if you see the link on the last comment you will see that in the range im trying to predict the function oscillates, this is caussing the high errors in the net, it will also of course spike up the MSE.
how can i handle this?
the point is able to handle this extreme cases

Comment: This image is unclear and doesn't tell me anything.  Is it possible to use the estimates to build a contour map?  This way, you will be able to compare the two and see the areas where it is struggling.

Comment: it was just an image of all the errors of all the training cases after 2000 epochs, what i meant to show was that there are "extreme" cases that arent accounted.
  2000 epochs that resulted in the following [surface](http://i.imgur.com/6jA4GYC.jpg)
this is the [real surface](http://i.imgur.com/DWKX3UZ.jpg)
in the case of the calculated surface take in consideration that some interpolations were made to be able to calculate it